# Managing persistence in DDD

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, domain-driven-design, persistence

Let's say that I want to create a blog application with these two simple persistence classes used with EF Code First or NHibernate and returned from repository layer:

```cs
public class PostPersistence
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public IList<LikePersistence> Likes { get; set; }
}

public class LikePersistence
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //... some other properties
}
```

I can't figure out a clean way to map my persistence models to domain models. I'd like my `Post` domain model interface to look something like this:

```cs
public interface IPost
{
   int Id { get; }
   string Text { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<ILike> Likes { get; }
   void Like();
}
```

Now how would an implementation underneath look like? Maybe something like this:

```cs
public class Post : IPost
{
   private readonly PostPersistence _postPersistence;
   private readonly INotificationService _notificationService;

   public int Id 
   { 
       get { return _postPersistence.Id }
   }

   public string Text 
   { 
       get { return _postPersistence.Text; }
       set { _postPersistence.Text = value; }
   }

   public IEnumerable<ILike> Likes
   {
       //this seems really out of place
       return _postPersistence.Likes.Select(likePersistence => new Like(likePersistence ));
   }

   public Post(PostPersistence postPersistence, INotificationService notificationService)
   {
       _postPersistence = postPersistence;
       _notificationService = notificationService;
   }

   public void Like()
   {
       _postPersistence.Likes.Add(new LikePersistence());
       _notificationService.NotifyPostLiked(Id);
   }
}
```

I've spent some time reading about DDD but most examples were theoretical or used same ORM classes in domain layer. My solution seems to be really ugly, because in fact domain models are just wrappers around ORM classes and it doens't seem to be a domain-centric approach. Also the way `IEnumerable<ILike> Likes` is implemented bothers me because it won't benefit from LINQ to SQL. What are other (concrete!) options to create domain objects with a more transparent persistence implementation?

Comment: What language is this? It's really helpful to tag your question with the programming language you're using. You should add C# and .Net to your question's tags.

Comment: I've added these tags, but my question is more platform independent. Any  answer written in an OO language would satisfy me.

Comment: Unfortunately EF is not ideal because you will either have to do something like what you described or have to 'expose' your class with auto properties and have a default paramless constructor if you want EF to manage your Entities

Answer (score 2):

One of the goals of persistence in DDD is [persistence ignorance](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/08/10/toward-persistence-ignorance-with-nhibernate-in-domain-driven-design/) which is what you seem to be striving for to some extent. One of the issues that I see with your code samples is that you have your entities implementing interfaces and referencing repositories and services. In DDD, entities should not implement interfaces which are just abstractions of itself and have instance dependencies on repositories or services. If a specific behavior on an entity requires a service, pass that service directly into the corresponding method. Otherwise, all interactions with services and repositories should be done outside of the entity; typically in an application service. The application service orchestrates between repositories and services in order to invoke behaviors on domain entities. As a result, entities don't need to references services or repositories directly - all they have is some state and behavior which modifies that state and maintains its integrity. The job of the ORM then is to map this state to table(s) in a relational database. ORMs such as NHibernate allow you to attain a relatively large degree of [persistence ignorance](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/08/10/toward-persistence-ignorance-with-nhibernate-in-domain-driven-design/).

**UPDATES**

> Still I don't want to expose method with an INotificationService as a
>   parameter, because this service should be internal, layer above don't
>   need to know about it.

In your current implementation of the `Post` class the `INotificationService` has the same or greater visibility as the class. If the `INotificationService` is implemented in an infrastructure layer, it already has to have sufficient visibility. Take a look at [hexagonal architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture) for an overview of layering in modern architectures.

As a side note, functionality associated with notifications can often be placed into handlers for [domain events](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/08/strengthening-your-domain-domain-events/). This is a powerful technique for attaining a great degree of decoupling.

> And with separate DTO and domain classes how would you solve
>   persistence synchronization problem when domain object doesn't know
>   about its underlying DTO? How to track changes?

A DTO and corresponding domain classes exist for very different reasons. The purpose of the DTO is to carry data across system boundaries. DTOs are not in a one-one correspondence with domain objects - they can represent part of the domain object or a change to the domain object. One way to track changes would be to have a DTO be explicit about the changes it contains. For example, suppose you have a UI screen that allows editing of a `Post`. That screen can capture all the changes made and send those changes in a command (DTO) to a service. The service would load up the appropriate `Post` entity and apply the changes specified by the command.

Comment: This link is really helpful and it partially solves problem stated in my reply to user1568656's post. Still I don't want to expose method with an `INotificationService` as a parameter, because this service should be internal, layer above don't need to know about it. And with separate DTO and domain classes how would you solve persistence synchronization problem when domain object doesn't know about its underlying DTO? How to track changes? Some code examples would be really helpful. (Sorry, I can't vote up, not enaugh reputation)

Comment: I really like the domain events idea. An entity doesn't need to know about notifications, it just fires an event and all interested services/entities register as listeners. I think that you misunderstood me about the second part: by DTOs I meant only my persistence classes. How to update a DTO AFTER state of a domain entity has changed? An entity doesn't know about its underlying DTO (possibly more than one). Is it also maintained by some kind events? For example `Post` entity exposes `LikeAdded(Like like)` event and in response some service creates a corresponding `LikePersistence`?

Comment: With an ORM like EF or NHibernate you don't need to have explicit persistence classes. The mappings are made directly between domain classes and relational tables. Thus, when you load up a domain class and leave the session open, any changes made to that domain class will automatically be persisted by the framework.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I read few resources like this one http://www.mehdi-khalili.com/orm-anti-patterns-part-4-persistence-domain-model which state that for large applications separate domain and persistence classes are recommended, because (despite all advantages) ORMs still restrict classes' development in some ways. What I failed to find are some code examples showing how to do that.

Comment: In using NHibernate I do find cases where I need to have an intermediary DTO to map to which in turn maps to the appropriate domain class. However, this has only been for [component mappings](http://ayende.com/blog/3937/nhibernate-mapping-component) and all that was required was a set of methods mapping between the domain class and DTO. In other words, there was no need for change tracking because component mappings were made for [DDD value objects](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/13/ddd-entities-and-value-objects.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a bit more research, see all the options and decide if it is really worth the hassle to go for a full DDD implementation, i ve been there myself the last few days so i ll tell you my experience.

EF Code first is quite promising but there are quite a few issues with it, i have an entry here for this
[Entity Framework and Domain Driven Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688750/entity-framework-and-domain-driven-design/13712316#13712316). With EF your domain models can be persisted by EF without you having to create a separate "persistence" class. You can use POCO (plain old objects) and get a simple application up and running but as i said to me it s not fully mature yet.

If you use LINQ to SQL then the most common approach would be to manually map a "data transfer object" to a business object. Doing it manually can be tough for a big application so check for a tool like Automapper. Alternatively you can simply wrap the DTO in a business object like

```
  public class Post
   {
      PostPersistence Post { get; set;}
      public IList<LikePersistence> Likes { get; set; }
       .....
   }
```

NHibernate: Not sure, havent used it for a long time.

My feeling for this (and this is just an opinion, i may be wrong) is that you ll always have to make compromises and you ll not find a perfect solution out there. If you give EF a couple more years it may get there. I think an approach that maps DTOs to DDD objects is probably the most flexible so looking for an automapping tool may be worth your time. If you want to keep it simple, my favourite would be some simple wrappers around DTOs when required.

Comment: I want to make it clear: I need separate classes for DTOs and domain entities. EF Code First and NHibernate are really flexible, but as far as I know they aren't fully transparent and in some ways destroy proper encapsulation. For example my `PostPersistence` exposes `IList<LikePersistence> Likes`. I don't want to allow for manual inserting into that list. Layer above domain should call `Like()` method instead which may include some additional processing.

Comment: You can consider EF with Detached entities and how it is supposed to work in N-Tier applications, this may give you (almost) everything you need but it will come with the price of you learning how to handle/attach objects & object graphs in EF and persist them.
I think you probably need to think about the state of things in 2-3 yyears, do you really want yourself and your colleagues to go though long mapping code or code full of events and notifications?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688750/entity-framework-and-domain-driven-design/13743471#13743471

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688750/entity-framework-and-domain-driven-design/13743471#13743471.